# How to check if Outlook has finished sending an email with an attachment?

Tags: delphi, email, outlook, attachment

Our Delphi application uses Outlook programmatic access when a user needs to send reports as PDF's to their customers. Normally there are no issues but there are a few reports where each customer gets their own copy and errors are being reported by Outlook when the number of customers is over 100.

We did track down the problem to Outlook not being able to create more than 100 temporary copies of the same attachment name, due to the auto-numbering it uses. This blog entry has a good example of the issue.

http://chentiangemalc.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/case-of-the-outlook-attachment-open-fail/

The preferred solution is to delete the files from the OutlookSecureTempFolder, however we can't do this during the processing as sometimes Outlook hasn't actually finished sending the email before we delete the temp file, which causes a similar error.

Is there a way to know, after you use .Send, when Outlook has actually sent the email and it is safe to delete the temp file? There does not seem to be any callback or event we can hook into.

Comment: Maybe then it is not a good idea to send more then 100 emails from one session? If you close Outlook instance after 50 messages sent, then it should shut down and cleanup everything correctly. Then you can recreate Outlook object (start up new instance) and send next 50 email and so on. Isn't it?

Comment: Check there are no items in the `Outbox` before starting next one?